# Can I have non owning shared pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, smart-pointers, c++14

### Intro

The question arose from the need for a conditional interface. It may be so that I fell into an XY problem, but (bottom line) I ended up needing a shared pointer that would ( based on a runtime choice ) either manage or not (own or not) a resource.

### Work so far

The following are some thoughts on a **non owning shared pointer**

1. Using placement new, eg:

   ```
   struct MyStruct {}; 
   MyStruct ms1; 
   std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> sp(new(&ms1) MyStruct);
   ```
2. Using a **dummy deleter**

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> spn(new MyStruct, [](MyStruct*){});
   ```

### Question

- Is there a standard proposed way?
- Is there a "don't do it" rule?
- Is there at least a better way?

### Notes

My class layout (where the non owning shared pointer will be used) looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct blah
{
    shared_ptr<T> _m;
};
```

Now, the `_m` member **may or may not** own a resource based on a runtime choice. The reason I'm not using `weak_ptr` is because `_m` may actually be an owning pointer.

Comment: Why not just use a `weak_ptr`, this is what it is designed for or am I missing something?

Comment: Use a `std::weak_ptr`, and then you can extract a `shared_ptr` as a local variable (via `lock()`) for the use of the resource.

Comment: @EdChum the smart pointer will be a class member. I'm trying to avoid using two members (a `weak` and a `shared` pointer) plus a flag to know which one is valid. Is there a way to always have just **one** member ?

Comment: @Niall Not a valid / working piece of code, just a compiling fragment to speculate on the possibility of using placement new to have non owning smart pointers. The question specificaly asks if it's valid of if there's a valid way to do it .

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou. If both members are of the same class (object), I see no reason for two members. The owning pointer (and hence to the parent object) owns it, there is no need at this point for an additional non-owning member.

Comment: I'd say that `weak_ptr` is the **only** valid thing, though. `shared_ptr` is meant to be owning, and it doesn't make sense not to have it own. Why maintain a reference count if you don't care about managing the object anyway? Using a `weak_ptr` you only have one member, too. Only locally when you actually use the object, you'll lock it, with a local variable -- no flag needed either, `weak_ptr::lock` already communicates whether or not it succeeded. That's both easy and straightforward **and** safe.

Answer (score 11):

The placement new is obviously UB, since it will in your snippet attempt to delete something on the stack. The empty deleter version will work but will allocate a reference counting block.

The trick is to use the crazy (ok, *aliasing*) constructor of `shared_ptr`:

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

that constructs a `shared_ptr` owning what `r` owns, but pointing to what `ptr` points to, i.e.:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> sp(std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>(), p);
```

This is guaranteed `noexcept` by the standard, and will not allocate anything. The standard even has a note that says

> [ *Note*: This constructor allows creation of an empty `shared_ptr`
>   instance with a non-null stored pointer. —*end note* ]

Answer (score 7):

The placement `new` will give you undefined behaviour (and likely a crash) on destruction - it will promptly call `delete` on something which was not created with `new`.

I'd go with the no-op deleter. The design may seem odd, but if you need such behaviour (and document it enough), it will work. I used something like this in one of my projects for a while, but then I got rid of the need for it.

Comment: I guess getting rid of the need for it is the big bet.

Comment: Definitely the no-op deleter; That's why boost has boost::null_deleter, which at one point was buried inside the serialization code, but is now in core. It is almost always unfortunate when you need to resort to this, but if you can't change an API, you can't....
(Edit) If all you're doing is to try to have a possibly non-owning pointer, shared_ptr<> is overkill; roll your own convenience class, or use unique_ptr with a deleter that keeps around a boolean to tell it if it needs to free. If shared ownership is desired in the owning case, shared_ptr is OK